# Ruby: MongoDB and stored js functions (not stored procedures!)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, mongomapper

I'm writing a site which will display objects from MongoDB, idea is to make it as flexible as possible. To do that I've created a collection `config` which consists of following objects:

```
      categories: {        
        "Title": { /// thats a displayed category title
          [ collection: "collection_name", ] /// defaultize to title.snake_case
          [ template: "some_template", ] /// defaultize to title.snake_case
          [ css: { /// object will be passed to template

          }, ]
          fields: {        
            "Field Title": {
              [name: "attribute_name" ,] /// defaultize to field_title.snake_case
              [required: true or false, ] /// defaultize to false
              [template: "template_name", ] /// defaultize to field_title.snake_case
              [ css: { /// same as above, passed to template
                // ..      
              }, ]         
              [validations: [
                function(field_value, record){
                  return []; /// this should be array with errors or empty if none
                },         
                ["validationName", ...] /// this should be one of functions defined in validations collection name or DBRef to it
              ], ]         
            },
            // ...         
          }                
        }                  
      }
```

snake_case is actually a `String` method known as `underscore` in ActiveSupport: "AsdAsd".underscore => "asd_asd".
Those `[]` define optional attributes.

Everything was fine and worked as expected until I've ran into validations.
Those validations are stored in MongoDB and using console I can do like that:

```
    > db.config.findOne().categories.text.exec("some_string", {...});
    [ ]
    >
```

Can i do the same from Ruby using MongoID or MongoMapper?
Or I should change my approach?

Thanks.